# input validation inside react js component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a login form in react js. my code is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Background.css';
import withStyles from '../../decorators/withStyles';
import Link from '../Link';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';

@withStyles(styles)
class Background extends Component {    
render() {
return (
    <form id="login">           
        <input id="username" placeholder="username" type="text"></input>    <br/><br/><br/>                                         
        <input id="password" placeholder="password" type="password"></input><br/><br/><br/><br/>                                                            
        <a id="btn" href="/search" onClick={Link.handleClick}>SUBMIT</a>                
    </form>
);
}  
}

export default Background;
```

I want validate username and password ie, {Link.handleClick} should be fired only if username and password are entered. Can I add a function inside this same component? Or how can I implement the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can validate username and password inside same component.
If I validate check when user input.
You can also find other react event here.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Try this one

```
validateUsername(event) {
    var username = event.target.value;
    /*validate something ...*/
}

validatePassword(event) {
    var password = event.target.value;
    /*validate something ...*/
}


render() {
    return (
        <form id="login">
            <input id="username" placeholder="username" type="text" onInput={this.validateUsername}></input> <br/><br/><br/>
            <input id="password" placeholder="password" type="password" onInput={this.validatePassword}></input><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <a id="btn" href="/search" onClick={Link.handleClick}>SUBMIT</a>
        </form>
    );
}
```